# How to add new child key-value to a React State object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, key

I'd like to add a new child key-value to an existing partent -happening on React. Let's say this is my state:

```
this.state = {
  genres: {
    Rock: '',
    Jazz: '',
    Pop: ''
  }
}
```

And this is my method:

```
addingGenre(tw) {
  this.setState({
    genres: { [tw]: '', }
    })
}
```

This is obviously not working, itoverwrites my full state --> {genres: tw}.

Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push to the current state. So it should be something like this:

```
addingGenre(tw) {
  this.setState({
    genres: { ...this.state.genres, [tw: '']}
    })
}
```

Comment: This worked! I just added "[]" to the "tw", otherwise it doesn't pass the actual value :) Thaks so much!

Comment: Yea I see that now @aZero forgot that it's a key value pair :) glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this -

```
addingGenre(tw) {
  const state = this.state; 
  state.genres[tw] = ''; 
  this.setState(state)
}
```

Comment: I did it, but because I'm a new member it's not displayed. This is the message they sent: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".

If there is any other way, please let me know and I'll do it :)

Comment: It's okay. Thanks. I hope you have no further doubts.